# Is it possible to get the caller context in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = {
    demo: function(){
      //get the caller context here
    }
}
//when this gets called, the caller context should be window.
test.demo();
```

I tried `arguments.callee` and `arguments.callee.caller`,and no luck...

Comment: What do you mean by "caller context"? Perhaps you mean the value of its *this* keyword?

Comment: @RobG,in my example,it should be `window`,effectually `this` keyword at calling site.

Comment: is there any reason you can't just pass it in? `test.demo(this)`?

Comment: @cycaHuH—That is passing a *this* value to the function, you can set it to anything from the call (which is one reason why it is so misleading to call *this* "context"). Since the value is supposed to be the caller's *this*, then it should be `test.demo.call(this)`, but I suspect the OP doesn't want to trash the function's default *this*, which would be `demo`.

Answer (score 53):

Since `this` keyword referes to `ThisBinding` in a `LexicalEnvironment`, and javascript (or ECMAScript) doesn't allow programmatic access to `LexicalEnvironment` (in fact, no programmatic access to the whole `Execution Context`), so it is **impossible** to get the context of caller.

Also, when you try `test.demo()` in a global context, there should be **no caller** at all, neither an attached **context** to the **caller**, this is just a **Global Code**, not a calling context.

Comment: @otakustay—You are aboslutely correct about not being able to reference variables as properties of other variable objects. But as a special case, global variables are made properties of the global object so you can in fact access variables in the calling context **if** it's global. You could test for the (deprecated, non–standard) `arguments.callee.caller` property and if it's `null` assume the call is from global code, then hope you're not in ES5 strict mode, get a reference to the global object and go from there.

Comment: This is where you run into problems with Node.JS and modules.

Answer (score 9):

By context, I assume you mean `this`? That depends on how the function is invoked, not from where it is invoked.

For example (using a Webkit console):

```
var test = {
    demo: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
test.demo();    // logs the "test" object
var test2 = test.demo;
test2();        // logs "DOMWindow"
test.demo.apply("Cheese"); // logs "String"
```

Incidentally, [`arguments.caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller) is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

The value of a function's `this` keyword is set by the call, it isn't "context". Functions have an execution context, which includes its *this* value. It is not defined by `this`.

In any case, since all functions have a `this` variable that is a property of its variable object, you can't reference any other `this` keyword in scope unless it's passed to the function. You can't directly access the variable object; you are dependent on variable resolution on the scope chain so `this` will always be the current execution context's `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Strange how we are talking about `this` except for
'Qix - MONICA WAS MISTREATED''s comment. Either you are able to capture

1. `window`,
2. worker `self`,
3. *`v8::Isolate` `v8::context` is extended in [fetch](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/runtime-apis/fetch-event/) for cloudflare workers* (or use `this` of the `class`), or
4. rename some other function-method's scope-`this`-context outside, so

this hypothetical situation has no use case.

```
var test = {
    demo: function(){
      //get the caller context here
    }
}

test.demo();
```

For closure, one could [have a dynamically named function factory for some reason](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/pull/17273), while maintaining its context like so:

```
function body () {}
var test = {
  demo: {
    [name]: function () {return body.apply(body, arguments);} 
       }[name];
```

Without for [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51349060/11711280), `thisArg` argument would be `{demo:fn()}`

```
var test = {demo:{}}
const createNamedFunc = (body) => {
  test.demo = return {
    [name]: function () {
      return body.apply(body, arguments);
         } } [name];
}
createNamedFunc(function body (){})
```

I gather *this* 'functional-method-parameter-object' is

1. **the deepest-functional-method-child** of the object-declarations
2. of *the global scope receiver[ object]*
3. passing it on, **until the next** non-object nor [-data-type](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_data_types.asp) **returnable type definition or instantiation**, [not necessarily declaration but always implement/extension scope interface](https://www.semicolonandsons.com/code_diary/architecture/the-difference-between-lexical-vs-dynamic-scope).