# How to get context of calling function/object?

Tags: javascript, this, function-constructor

```
function define(prop, value) {
    Object.defineProperty( /* context of caller */ , prop, {value: value});
}

function F() {
    define('x', 42);
}

var f = new F();
```

Is there a way to get context (inline commented in code above) of the calling function?

It works fine if I bind to this (replace comment to `this`) and inside `F` constructor declare `var def = define.bind(this);`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679053/is-it-possible-to-get-the-caller-context-in-javascript, looks like you have to pass `this` to define

Comment: Yeah, question is there a way to do it without passing `this`

Comment: `define.call(this, 'x', 42);`? Then `Object.defineProperty(this, ...)`

Comment: ...or just put your `define` function on `F.prototype` like `F.prototype.define = define`, so you can do `this.define(...)` in the constructor, and `this` in `define` will automatically be your object.

Comment: @CrazyTrain, putting define in `F.prototype` and `this.define(...)` looks better than binding, but that isn't common case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to get context of calling function/object?

You can't, you'll have to make it available to your `define` function explicitly (pass it in as an argument, etc.).

And this is a Good Thing<sup>(tm)</sup>. :-) The last thing you'd want is functions having access to the caller's context and changing things in an uncontrolled way.