# javascript - how to access the caller function context object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following situation:

- a main script with commons methods
- several other scripts which are using them

```js
(function() {
    window.mainMethod = function(param) {
        //...
        //console.log("I'm calling this method from context "+myContext.name); [CAN'T DO]
        console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
    }
})();

// Object A
(function() {
    var myContext = {};
    myContext.name = "context A";
    myContext.fn = function fnA() {
        window.mainMethod("param A1");
        // ...
        window.mainMethod("param A2");
        // ...
        window.mainMethod("param A3");
        // etc...
    }();
})();

// Object B
(function() {
    var myContext = {};
    myContext.name = "context B";
    myContext.fn = function fnB() {
        window.mainMethod("param B1");
        // ...
        window.mainMethod("param B2");
        // ...
        window.mainMethod("param B3");
        // etc...
    }();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

What I'm trying to do is to **log** in my mainMethod **the context where I'm calling that method from**.

First thing I camed up with was to add a parameter to each call :

`window.mainMethod("some parameter 1", myContext);`

BUT since this is only for log purposes (not functional) and I have thousands of these occorrences to modify, i would like to avoid that.

So I thought maybe there is a way to access to `myContext` object through the `callee.caller` property, but this is where I went so far.

```
window.mainMethod = function(parameter) {
    //console.log("I'm calling mainMethod from context " + myContext.name);
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller.name);
}
```

This will print out the function name (`fnA`), but still can't access the object where the function is stored (`myContext`).

Any suggestion?

---

ps: i'm also open for workarounds like, i don't know, binding some hidden property to the function and then retrieve it with `arguments.callee.caller.myHiddenProperty` ... is it possible?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679053/is-it-possible-to-get-the-caller-context-in-javascript you cannot access caller context this way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you find out the caller function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript)

Comment: @freedomn-m that's not the question here

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi i'm sorry but i seriously don't know what are you talking about.. i mean it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to change the thousands of calls to `mainMethod` you have, you need to alter the functions that call it (`fn`). The solution is to keep `fn` as a function instead the result of a function like you have currently, then add the context to it that you can later invoke from inside the `mainMethod` function :

```
(function() {
    window.mainMethod = function() {
        // will print the context that has been added to the function object
        console.log(arguments.callee.caller.context);
    }
})();

// Object A
(function() {
    var myContext = { name: 'A' };
    myContext.fn = function fnA() {
        window.mainMethod();
    // notice that I removed the `()` to keep `fn` as a function inside `myContext`
    };
    // now add the context inside the function object
    myContext.fn.context = myContext;
    // then just call it
    myContext.fn();
})();
```

Comment: thanks, this is a nice workaround even if i have to manually set that property on every function (but still better then changing all the calls)

Comment: This is definitely a bit hacky, but it serves the purpose if you do not want the change the numerous calls. But in a later time, you would benefit alot from refactoring all the code to use classes.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I think you're going to get is to explicitly change the context using `call`

```js
(function(){
  window.mainMethod = function(param){
        //...
        //console.log("i'm calling this method from context "+myContext.name); [CAN'T DO]
        console.log(this.name, arguments.callee.caller.name, param);
    }
})();


// Object A
(function(){
   var myContext = {};

   myContext.name = "context A";
   myContext.fn = function fnA(){
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param A1");
      // ...
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param A2");
      // ...
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param A3");
      // etc...
  }();

})();

// Object B
(function(){
   var myContext = {};

   myContext.name = "context B";
   myContext.fn = function fnB(){
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param B1");
      // ...
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param B2");
      // ...
      window.mainMethod.call(myContext,"param B3");
      // etc...
  }();

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yeah, i thoght that too, but i still have to modify every single occurrence of these calls, which is what i'm trying to avoid here