# How to get all the properties assigned to the function object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In javascript I can create an object with the same name as a function, or i can assign a new property to the function object, like:

```js
    function func(){
    console.log("inside func");
    }

    func.a = "new property";
    console.log(func.a);
    func();
    console.log(func);
```

How do i see what are the properties assigned(and possibly their values) to the function object?

Comment: that's not my question actually, console.dir is still printing function, i want the property list of the function object. `console.log({ ...func })` works in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Functions are special type of **Objects** in JavaScript.

Unlike other programming languages, functions are special type of **Objects** in JavaScript. They have their own methods (viz. bind, call, apply and a hell lot more) like other objects do. Therefore, when you assign a prop `a` to your `func`, you are not creating a new `func` object. Instead, it's the same `func` object (function object) and you are just creating a new prop `func.a` on it. Read [this](http://www.dofactory.com/tutorial/javascript-function-objects) for more info. Also, you can do something like the following to print all the props you have assigned to a function object (or any object in JS):

```
for (var prop in func) {
  console.log(prop); // This will print 'a' in your case
}
```

Comment: thanks, in that case, what if i want to see what are the properties assigned to the function (function object)?

Comment: @vikrant You can parse a plain object from it and log that: `console.log({ ...func })`

Comment: why not Hail the entire world :)

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way might be this:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(func);
```

Comment: it only prints out the property, but doesn't show the value of the property

Answer (score 0):

The function is implicitely cast to string when `console.log()` is called, and by default `toString()` only returns the code of your function (see the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString)).

```
function func(){
  console.log("inside func");
}
func.toString = function() {
  return "a = " + this.a;
}
func.a = "new attribute";
console.log(func.a);
func();
console.log(func);
```